# Python global and local variable inside function

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, global, local

I am confused with this part of the code (what I pasted here is simplified version of the actual code).

When I run the following code:

```
def function_1():
    apples = 0
    apples += 1
    print(apples)


while True:
    function_1()
```

And, the result is:

1
1
1
...

Which makes total sense to me, while loop will call the function each time, and apples value is set to 0, after that 1 is added to apples and I get a result 1.

But, when I run this code:

```
apples = 0
def function_1():
    global apples
    apples += 1
    print(apples)



while True:
    function_1()
```

The result is:

1
2
3
...

This is what is confusing for me, shouldnt the result be the same as the one in the previous example? Each time while loop calls the function, apples value should be 0, only this time it is global variable and the function should check that value instead of having that value inside the function (locally). Why does the function increase the value instead each time going back to apples = 0?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you declared and initialised the variable `apples` inside the defined function, and in the second example, you declared and initialised the variable `apples` outside the function. Let's discuss each case separately.

**Case 1 - `apples` inside function**
In this case, when the `while loop` is calling the function, at first, the value of `apples` is 0 and it is iterated by 1, and that 1 is printed. The second time, the value of apple is resetted to 0, since the first line inside the `function_1` is `apples = 0`. Due to this, the iterated value 1 is printed, and it is continued until the while loop breaks.

**Case 2 - `apples` outside function**
In this case, the value of `apples` is 0 at first. When the function is called inside the while loop, the value of `apples` is iterated by 1 and this value,ie 1 is printed. This current value of `apples` isn't changing, when the function is called for the second time. The value of `apples` is currently 1 now,according to the previous function call, and it's iterated by 1, which gives 2 and it's printed. Since the current value isn't replaced anywhere before the iteration inside the function, the value will increase by 1 every time.

I think you might have got the answer right now. Up-vote my answer if you this I gave the best explanation :)